# Sonata change default format_date

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-sonata

I have installed the `SonataIntlBundle`bundle. The default format_date results in a format like `day-number month-name year`.

`{{ date_time_object | format_date }} => '1 août 2011'`[Source](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/intl/master/doc/reference/datetime.html)

Now, I want to change this default to `dayNumber-monthNumber-yearNumber` for people with a english translation (en) and to `monthNumber-dayNumber-yearNumber`for people with a dutch translation (nl). How should I do this and is their any documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{ date_time_object | format_date('MM-dd-yyyy', 'nl') }}` would work. As defined in the bottom of the documentation.

**Edit**

To do it globally you can extend [DateTimeHelper](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataIntlBundle/blob/master/Templating/Helper/DateTimeHelper.php) class and set `sonata.intl.templating.helper.datetime.class` parameter to that class in `app/config/config.yml`.

Comment: Yes, however, in this way I have to define this format at every place I use the format_date and for every language.

Comment: Thanks, extended and set the parameter