# Format for time display?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I am making application with symfony2 and sonata-admin bundle.

```
public function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('id')
        ->add('fromDate');
```

it shows time like this

```
September 1, 2013 02:00
```

so I changed

```
 -  ->add('fromDate');
 +  ->add('fromDate',null,array('format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
```

but it still show the same.

please give me how to use format for time display?

Comment: This should be part of your twig template.

Comment: @cheesemacfly That's just one way to do it, and not necessarily the best.

Comment: @likeitlikeit well, the way the date is rendered should be part of the view since it has only a display purpose, or am I missing something?

Comment: If you do internationalisation for instance, you might be better off using a system-wide format like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432652/sonata-change-default-format-date)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using

```
->add('fromDate','datetime',array('date_format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
```

By the way, the relevant code is [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/DateTimeType.php). I think your `format` option gets overwritten by the system, so it's important to use `date_format` instead. For an application-wide solution, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432652/sonata-change-default-format-date) too.

Comment: I wanted to know how to do this to format a unix timesampt and the date type. using the type 'date' works and displays something like 'October 24, 2013', but the date_format doesn't change it. any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

If you use SonataIntlBundle then date formats are:

```
$list->add('createdAt', 'date', array(
    'pattern' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
))
```

described in https://docs.sonata-project.org/projects/SonataIntlBundle/en/3.x/reference/datetime/#php-usage
and its formats here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php

Comment: `'pattern'` did it for me

Comment: "pattern" values are differ from php datetime constants and can be founded here http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime

Answer (score 3):

Nothing from the above had worked for me, so I ventured to inspect the page source, which pointed me towards template used:

```
<!-- START
    fieldName: date
    template: SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_date.html.twig
    compiled template: SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_date.html.twig
    -->
<td class="sonata-ba-list-field sonata-ba-list-field-date" objectId="1">11.03.17</td>
<!-- END - fieldName: date -->
```

And after inspecting the template I've found  the correct option filed name:

```
{%- elseif field_description.options.format is defined -%}
```

So I made my Admin code like this

```
->add('date', null, ['format' => 'd/m/Y'])
```

and it worked.

Note that format is the regular `date()` format, and one have to use just a single placeholder mark, like `y` for year, as `yyyy` produces `2017201720172017`.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old thread, but I hope it will help someone...

Try to add this, like carzogliore said (but quotes are missed from datetime):

```
->add('fromDate', 'datetime', array('format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to indicate that "DateTime" is the type you watn to use and then use the format key, for instance:

```
->add('fromDate',datetime,array('format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
```

Internally, Sonata will use list_datetime.html.twig as you are refering "Datetime" as type and that contains format options. Below you can see the list_datetime.html.twig sonata base implementation:

```
{% extends admin.getTemplate('base_list_field') %}

{% block field %}
{%- if value is empty -%}
    &nbsp;
{%- elseif field_description.options.format is defined -%}
    {{ value|date(field_description.options.format) }}
{%- else -%}
    {{ value|date }}
{%- endif -%}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

my 'problem' was different. 
Because I have the sonata intl bundle active, it uses it to format the datetime list.

```
->add('startAt', 'datetime', array(
                'dateType' => IntlDateFormatter::LONG,
                'timeType' => IntlDateFormatter::SHORT
            ))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the modern versions of Sonata I have managed to make it work like this:

```
$listMapper->add('dateadd', 'datetime', array('format' => 'y-m-d H:m:s'));
```