# How not to use english label for month name?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I am showing timedate select box by this code

```
public function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{

    $formMapper
        ->with('General')  

         ->add('toDate',null,array(                
                'widget' => 'choice');
```

however it uses english name for month label,such as Jan,Feb,Mar...

I want to use number instead of english label.

How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
->add('toDate',null,array(        
                'format' => ''dd - M - yyyy'',        
                'widget' => 'choice');
```

Comment: I see that I have typed up wrong quotes around format string, have you changed them?

Comment: I think your answer is correct,but in my circumstances I have to use  'date_format'. this is reference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16268813/format-for-time-display